# Weird behavoir of scrolling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to achieve is a simple scroll to function, which always will scroll to same point regarding scrollTop position.

I thought using window.scroll will be a good approach here, cause I am able to read current scrollTop value, as I sad it's not workin, on some browsers I am not able to scroll(IE), on others (Chrome, Firefox) after clicking  tag connected to this func. I got auto scroll behaviour, a little bit up and then a little bit down.

I don't want to use scrollTo plugin or others cause it's the only place on my page with such funcionality.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(y);
    var mainBanner = $('header').height();

    if (y > 1 && y < mainBanner) {
        $('#slideUpHead').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: mainBanner - y}, 600);
        });
    }
    else if(y < 1){
            $('#slideUpHead').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: y + mainBanner}, 600);
            });
    }
    else {

    }


});
```

here's my second approach, partially working:

```
myScroll = function (){

    var mainBannerH = $('header').height();
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (y > 1 && y < mainBannerH) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: mainBannerH - y}, 600);

    }
    else if(y < 1){

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: y + mainBannerH}, 600);

    }
    else {
        console.log("It's not working properly");
    }

};



$('#slideUpHead').click(myScroll);
```

Comment: You `got auto scroll behaviour, a little bit up and then a little bit down`, because you're re-attaching a different click handler again and again whenever `window.onscroll` event fires.

Comment: I did second approach (edited post), but it works partially, only for y < 1, for y between 1 and mainBannerH it somtetimes scroll a little down sometimes up, but only once, auto scroll disappeared. The thing is I am receiving scrollTop value only once at page load, how can I recheck it?

Comment: Solution found, can You check if eneything may be made better?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being the following solution works just fine, thanks to Ahmad I have changed my approach and get scrollTop position a little bit differently, not 100% sure why but it works.

```
myScrollTo = function (){

    var mainBannerH = $('header').height();
    var myPos = $('html,body').scrollTop();

    if ( myPos > 1 && myPos < mainBannerH) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: mainBannerH - myPos}, 600);

    }
    else if(myPos < 1){

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: myPos + mainBannerH}, 600);

    }
    else {
        console.log("It's not working properly");
    }

};



$('#slideUpHead').click(myScrollTo);
```